# Finding the values of avg and total month/rainfall, in Python

Tags: python, datetime

so my issue with this one it is the assemble the datetime function with a new class made by my own, which it should give the year and the month, like on the images, to store the rainfall data. I'm new to this language, so if I can get any suggestions or paths to start on, I would appreciate that.

Also, this is the code that I tried so far, like I said, I don't know on how to structure it(I put the value of 4 for the range of 0-4 for the random.randit):

```
from random import randint
class datetime:
    def __init__(self, month_name, rainfall_year, value=4): 
        self.month = month_name
        self.year= rainfall_year
        self.value = value
```

Expected output:

```
--------------
June (2022) = 1
May (2022) = 2
April (2022) = 3
March (2022) = 1
February (2022) = 3
January (2022) = 2
December (2021) = 0
November (2021) = 4
October (2021) = 4
September (2021) = 0 
August (2021) = 1
July (2021) = 2
-----------------------
Total rainfall: 23
Average rainfall 1.91
```

Thank you and any constructive opinions or suggestions are accepted as well to keep learning this path, thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Please put your expected output in the question, not as images or links.

Comment: Sorry, I've already edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks quite good so far. Don't declare a new class with a name `datetime` which is an existing entity. You could pass a `date` object as a constructor argument if you wanted to incorporate it in the implementation like so

```
from random import randint
from datetime import date


class RainData():
    def __init__(self, rain_date: date, value: int):
        self.rain_date = rain_date
        self.value = value


rd = RainData(rain_date=date(2022, 10, 1), value=randint(0, 4))
print(f"{rd.rain_date.strftime('%B (%Y)')} = {rd.value}")
# Output: October (2022) = 2
```

To generate data on all 12 months you'd do the following in place of the last two lines here. It loops over numbers from 1 to 12 and adds a `RainData` entry to a list called `year_data` and prints it.

```
year_data = [RainData(rain_date=date(2022, m, 1), value=randint(0, 4)) for m in range(1, 13)]
[print(f"{rd.rain_date.strftime('%B (%Y)')} = {rd.value}") for rd in year_data]
```

Simpler way to achieve the same outcome looks like this

```
year_data = []
for month in range(1, 13):
    rd = RainData(rain_date=date(2022, month, 1), value=randint(0, 4))
    year_data.append(rd)
    print(f"{rd.rain_date.strftime('%B (%Y)')} = {rd.value}")
```

**As a side note**, if you'd want to extend another class, e.g. `datetime` you would use syntax like

```
class RainData(datetime):
```

which gives you full features of `datetime` class but with the option of adding your own content. Reference here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

I just don't see it making much sense in your currently described requirements.

Comment: Just the last question (Sorry for bothering), for the avg and total is with a function of the sum? or keep it simple and use the round function?...

Comment: Total is indeed a `sum()`. For example `total = sum([rd.value for rd in year_data])`. Average is just that divided by the number of months. You can easily get the length of the list with `len(year_data)` if for example the year is not over yet and you only have data on 5 months so far `average = total / len(year_data)`